# Is it possible to bind onClick to specific activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to build a single window app.
I have one layout (one xml file) and two activities. A button on the first activity starts the second activity, which is an infinite quiz. Then the second activity modifies some of the views (displays series of questions).

**The button purpose is to finish the second activity if it's up, then start it again.**

The problem is when I click the button the second time, the app crashes. Per my understanding, it's because it can't find the onClick method in the second activity code. This is the error message:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method startQuiz(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'buttonStart'

I am looking for a way to bind the onClick of that button to only the main activity.
Is it possible? I Would appreciate any help.

My button xml:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:onClick="startQuiz"
        android:text="@string/start"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/arithMul" />
```

My main activity:

```
/** Called when the user taps the Start button */
public void startQuiz(View view) {
    finishActivity();
    initQuiz();
}

public void initQuiz() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuizActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void finishActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("finish.quiz");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

My second activity (QuizActivity):

```
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textQuestion = null;
EditText textAnswer = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // register to finish broadcast message
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("finish.quiz");
    registerReceiver(broadcast_reciever, filter);

    // access main activity layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // main layout text views
    ConstraintLayout layoutChoose = findViewById(R.id.constraintLayoutQuiz);
    layoutChoose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewQuestion);
    textAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAnswer);

    // start the quiz
    startQuizSequence();
}

// register for broadcast to finish this activity
BroadcastReceiver broadcast_reciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        //finish the activity
        finish();
    }
};

private void startQuizSequence() {
    ...
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you could use `findByViewId` in both activities to find the button and explicitly set `onClickListener`s in each activity.

Comment: But what if the button has only one functionality within my main activity, and it's not suppose to do anything in the other activity?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is when I click the button the second time, the app crashes. Per my understanding, it's because it can't find the onClick method in the second activity code.

You're correct. When you're using Button with `android:onClick` attribute like the following:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="startQuiz"
        ...
         />
```

You're expected to create a method similar with the attribute value like this:

```
public void startQuiz(View v) {

}
```

You need to add the same method to another activity using the XML layout.

But, It becomes a problem when you're trying to rename the Button View and rename the `android:onClick` value to reflect the change. But then you forgot to rename the method in the Activity.

So, you need to decouple the layout from the code. Instead using a `android:onClick` attribute, you need to set the Button click listener. Update your Button view to something like this:

```
<!-- I usually use a more readable id for the button -->
<Button
        android:id="@+id/start_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
         />
```

Then, set the click listener:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_btn);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // do something here.
  }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not going to rename the button dynamically. Basically, I just want the button to restart the second activity (e.g. finish it and then start it again).